# Rubik's cube: rotate 2 opposite corners

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

Is there an faster algorithm to rotate 2 opposite corners?
I can't find anything else but doing the sexy move multiple times.

Comment: "The sexy move"? Is that an actual cube-solving move?

Comment: What do you mean by opposite - diagonally opposite in the same face, or on opposite sides of the cube (not sharing a face)?

Comment: @F1Krazy R U R' U' or some rotation/symmetry of that move. Surprisingly useful and really quick to perform.

Comment: @F1Krazy [Yes.](https://www.speedsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Sexy_Move)

Comment: I mean on a diagonal, so not sharing any faces.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: Comments regarding use of VTC vs downvoting have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63047/discussion-on-question-by-cristiano-marchettini-rubiks-cube-rotate-2-opposite).

Answer (score 4):

This algorithm can be adapted to do what you need.

```
F D' F' D F D' F' U' F D F' D' F D F' U
```

**To deal with non adjacent corners where one corner is on the right hand side of F (corners in a diagonal)**, rotate U twice instead of once in the algorithm, i.e.

```
F D' F' D F D' F' U2 F D F' D' F D F' U2`
```

If both corners are far opposites (do not share any faces), make sure one corner is on the right hand side of `F` (as before), rotate `L2` and then apply the original algorithm, and rotate `L2` to finish.

Comment: What is T? I haven't seen that notation before.

Comment: This would rotate 2 corners sharing the same face, I'm looking for something where the 2 corners are on a diagonal

Answer (score 1):

Twist two diagonally opposite corners.  One is twisted clockwise while the other anti-clockwise.

U L U' R2 U L' U' R2 D L2 D' R2 D L2 D' R2

Answer (score 0):

This rotates front right clockwise and back left counterclockwise:

```
(R'D2R B'U2B)X2
```

You can rotate the cube to avoid having to turn the back side but this orientation has the handy "hardy har, bub" mnemonic.

Answer (score 0):

Consider algorithm 25 on this page:
https://solvethecube.com/algorithms

It is this:
F' (r U R' U') (r' F R)